# Does new instance of stream passed to a method automatically get disposed?

Tags: c#, stream

Assume we have the following class

```
public class TestProsessor
{

    public void Process(Stream stream)
    {
        // do not dispose stream.
    }
}
```

Then it is called like this

```
public void Main()
{

   var processor = new TestProsessor();
   processor.Process(new MemoryStream());
}
```

Does the new instance of `MemoryStream` passed get automatically disposed? Or I must dispose it before the end of the code as follow?

```
public void Main()
{

   var processor = new TestProsessor();
   using var stream = new MemoryStream();

   processor.Process(stream);
}
```

How can I approve that the answer is valid?

Comment: the using statement should dispose it off at the end of its scope

Comment: @Codesmith that if I use the using as per the second example. In the first example, I do not use `using`. I pass the new instance to another class.

Comment: I don't think it will be disposed off at the end of the function, garbage collector will eventually get it to, but it might linger for a bit and cause performance issues, until then

Comment: Why would it be disposed? You never call `Dispose`, or any `using` statements. That said, for `MemoryStream`, disposing it doesn't do anything substantial (unlike a `FileStream` for example).

Comment: `IDisposable` isn't magic. Nothing happens automatically unless you use a `using`. So `Process` itself will not dispose, only the outer function with the `using` will do so.